# RabbitMQ Erlang SSL configuration: dhfile

Tags: ssl, erlang, rabbitmq

I am trying to improve the TLS security of my RabbitMQ server.  I read here

http://ezgr.net/increasing-security-erlang-ssl-cowboy/

that a Diffie-Hellman params file *dhfile* can be specified in the RabbitMQ Erlang SSL config.  After adjusting my RabbitMQ configuration accordingly, like this

```
%% -*-erlang-*-
%% See http://ezgr.net/increasing-security-erlang-ssl-cowboy/
[{ssl,
  [{versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1', tlsv1]}]},
 {rabbit,
  [{ssl_listeners, [5671]},
   {ssl_options,
    [{cacertfile, "/opt/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/ca.pem"},
     {certfile, "/opt/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.pem"},
     {keyfile, "/opt/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-key.pem"},
     {verify, verify_peer},
     {versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1', tlsv1]},
     {dhfile, "/opt/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/dh-params.pem"},
     {ciphers,
      [
       "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
       "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
       "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384", 
       "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
       "ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA",
       "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
       "ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",
       "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384", 
       "ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384",
       "DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384", 
       "DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256",
       "AES256-GCM-SHA384", 
       "AES256-SHA256",
       "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
       "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
       "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256", 
       "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
       "ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
       "ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
       "ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256", 
       "ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256",
       "DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256", 
       "DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256",
       "AES128-GCM-SHA256", 
       "AES128-SHA256",
       "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA",  
       "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA",
       "DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA", 
       "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA",
       "ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA", 
       "AES256-SHA",
       "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA", 
       "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA",
       "DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA", 
       "ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA",
       "ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA", 
       "AES128-SHA"
      ]
     },
     {honor_cipher_order, true},
     {secure_renegotiate, true},
     {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]}]},
 {kernel,
  [{net_ticktime, 120}]}
].
```

Starting RabbitMQ and forcing a TLS connection that requires cipher ECDHE, I would expect a Server Temp key of 2048 bits.  However, that is not the result that obtains

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect msgs01:5671 -tls1_2 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 
...
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3129 bytes and written 278 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 6DAAFE1D336206CFCE35D056427635B79F72B2D4E492C734CD6F0016EFE96F67
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 93CE3B03C2634CC1AA266DDFA2737B48EA949CA6A56E6FC785A813F649E5378118247C6C8A36A1D8CF1F8598B30A0464
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1464540032
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Why is the RabbitMQ server not manifesting a 2048 bit temporary key size?

Does the result depend on the version of openssl the underlying erlang runtime is using?  How would I learn what this version is?

Thank you.

EDIT1:  Verifying the dhfile argument is the right path and contains correctly formatted data:

```
$ docker exec rabbit cat /opt/rabbitmq/etc/rabbitmq/dh-params.pem | openssl dhparam -text  -noout
    DH Parameters: (2048 bit)
        prime:
            00:eb:b5:46:30:28:43:dd:5d:31:6f:0e:94:00:19:
            ...
            af:f3
        generator: 2 (0x2)
```

EDIT2:  RabbitMQ version:  3.6.2; Erlang version:  18.3

Comment: It certainly depends on the openssl version used by Erlang. Some of the more recent algorithms are not available in older openssl versions and many LTS systems, especially RedHat, are shipped with quite outdated openssl version. I was looking for SO answer detailing how to get the version but can't find it now. There is a command to list all supported ciphers by a specific openssl version.